# Updating BIOS via USB drive and q-flash, q-flash says install complete, but nothing is updated

Tags: bios, motherboard

I can see the new BIOS file on the USB drive and when I select it everything appears to install correctly and the computer reboots, but all of my settings are still changed, q-flash is still version 2.15 (should have upgraded as well).  I don't have BIOS lock turned on or anything like that.  It's a Gigabyte MA790XT-UD4P.

Comment: Which BIOS version do you have installed and which one tried you to install?

Answer (score 0):

Award is the BIOS.  I just used CPU-Z and it actually reported that my BIOS is the new version .  Not sure why it didn't update Q-Flash and retained all of my settings though.